# Graphs and their subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = \{v_G, e_G\}$ and $H = \{ v_H, e_H \}$ be graphs with vertex sets $v_G$, $v_H$, and edge sets $e_G, e_H$, respectively.  Let $S_G$ be the set of sub-graphs of $G$ and $S_H$ be the set of sub-graphs of $H$.  Is there any efficient way to determine which elements of $S_G$ are isomorphic to which elements of $S_H$, or to determine if no such isomorphisms, other than the empty sub-graph, exist?

Comment: $G$ and $H$ both have the empty graph as a subgraph, so there is at least one pair of isomorphic subgraphs, but usually there will we many more of course.

Comment: good point.  Edited

Comment: Apparently, not at this point:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem

Comment: Well, if $G$ or $H$ is the empty graph, no subgraphs of $G$ and $H$ other than the empy ones are isomorphic. Otherwise each $G$ end $H$ contain a subgraph consisting of a single node, so these form a pair of isomorphic subgraphs.

Comment: Yes, and I suspect it just gets harder from there.  I think I was a bit imprecise.  I might ask another question to clarify, but here is what I was going for:  assume that I have an equality relation "=" defined on the vertices so that, for two vertices, $v_1 = v_2$ means that they belong to the same equivalence class.  I want to find all subgraphs in $H$ and $G$ for which not only is there an isomorphism but also corresponding vertices belong the same equivalence class.  From the answer below, it looks like this is a painfully hard problem...

Comment: However, I think I just solved my own problem: first find the isomorphisms, then check the equivalence classes.

Comment: If i may ask, what do you intend to use this for? I suspect that for all but very small graphs the number of isomorphisms will be far to large to calculate.

Comment: However, the condition with the equivalenece classes may be strong enough to make it tractable. I suggest you read this page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_product_of_graphs  You can modyfy the algorithm there to find all isomorphisms that satisfy the equivalence class condition without first having to find all isomorphisms

Comment: It's for a project I'm working on where I'd like to see if one computer program, written by a student, produces "similar" output to another, written by an instructor.  Since the student may choose to output things in a different order, or may only output certain things (if their code fails on a particular condition, say), then the output can be modeled as a graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_common_subgraph_isomorphism_problem) wikipedia article, the problem of finding the largest common subgraph is NP-hard. Since this problem is easier than finding all common subgraphs it follows that there is no easy way to find all the common subgraphs.